# PHP-MySQL inserts "Array" into a table in a foreach loop with Simple HTML Dom library

Tags: php, mysql, simple-html-dom

I have a piece of code similar to below:

```
    include 'simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php';
    ...
    ...
    foreach ($files as $file){
    $results= array();
        if(substr($file->getAttribute('href'),0,strlen($lookfor))==$lookfor){
            $URLs= $file->getAttribute('href');
            echo $URLs ."<br>";
            $html = file_get_html($URLs);
            foreach($html->find('div.postDisplay') as $post) {
                $item['date']     = $post->find('p.id.post-date', 0)->plaintext;
                $item['location']    = $post->find('p.id.post-location', 0)->plaintext;
                $title = $item['title']     = $post->find('h1.id.post-title', 0)->plaintext;
                $item['post'] = $post->find('div.post', 0)->plaintext;
                $results[] = $item;
            }
    print_r($results) ."</br>";
    ...
    ...
    ...
    $my_id ="1";
    $photos = "1";
    $insert_query = mysqli_query($db_connect, "INSERT INTO jackson.data (
        my_id, photos, results) VALUES (
        '$my_id', '$photos', '$results')");
```

The code echos the `$results` values in the browser perfectly fine; however, when I inserted the data into the database, `results` field only stores the `"Array"` as values. So, is there something I'm missing? and how can I insert the HTML format of the `$results` values which is echoing on my browser rather than the plain text?

Comment: @user1613360, thanks for your comment. I added the insert query. also, how about `outertext` method? I found the methods here http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm

Comment: Yeah you can use that but you should copy all their css and other properties to display the contents properly and moreover you can't customize the way the contents is displayed in your site.Check my edited answer it's a much more refined way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You are using print_r which outputs the array with index and that's why the browser displays the result perfectly.I think you are using the variable $results in your insert query and that's why it fails as it contains an array.Try something like this:
Change your table structure to

```
jackson.data (my_id, photos, title,date,location,post)
```

and put the insert statement into the foreach loop and insert the values accordingly.

Example

```
 foreach($html->find('div.postDisplay') as $post) {
                $item['date']     = $post->find('p.id.post-date', 0)->plaintext;
                $item['location']    = $post->find('p.id.post-location', 0)->plaintext;
                $title = $item['title']     = $post->find('h1.id.post-title', 0)->plaintext;
                $item['post'] = $post->find('div.post', 0)->plaintext;
                $query=mysqli_query($db_connect,"INSERT INTO jackson.data (
    my_id, photos, title,date,location,post) VALUES (
    '$my_id', '$photos', '$item['title'],$item['date'],.....)");
            }
```

For html formatting:

Do something like this:

```
 echo "<html><body>";

 foreach($html->find('div.postDisplay') as $post) {
                    $item['date']     = $post->find('p.id.post-date', 0)->plaintext;
                    $item['location']    = $post->find('p.id.post-location', 0)->plaintext;
                    $title = $item['title']     = $post->find('h1.id.post-title', 0)->plaintext;
                    $item['post'] = $post->find('div.post', 0)->plaintext;
                    $query=mysqli_query($db_connect,"INSERT INTO jackson.data (
        my_id, photos, title,date,location,post) VALUES (
        '$my_id', '$photos', '$item['title'],$item['date'],.....)");

                 echo "<div class=\"my_post\"><h1>".$item['title']."</h1>"."<br />Published:". $item['date']."<br />".$item['location']."<br /><br />".$item['post']."</div>";
}
echo "</body></html>";
```

In your css you can have something like this:

```
.my_post
{
  margin:0 auto;//centers the contents
   font-weight:bold;
   font:fontname;
   font-size:16px;
   color:brown;
   padding-top:15px;//Adjusts the gap between two posts;


}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I changed the `$item['post']` to `$item['results']`, but still it inserts the Array as a value.

Comment: I tried to `serialize($results)` and insert the `".mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $results)."`, but it returns an empty value

Comment: @Apiah No don't do that $results is an array variable only way to access it is to use index in your case you can call it using $result[0],$result[1]....Let me explain your input is <html><body><tags>Content</tags> you are using html dom parser to take the contents based on tags and each content type like title,date etc are stored in $item['title'],$item['data'] so you should store them separately but you are try to aggregate everything into $result which makes all the valuable information like title,content,date and makes  the data inaccessible.

Comment: What you can do is you can have a query like "insert into table(title,date,location,content) values($item['title'],$item['date'],$item['location'],$item['post'])" inside the foreach loop and later you can retrieve the contents using select queries.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
 "<pre>".print_r($result,true)."</pre>"
```

to store in db to display html output similar to browser